# Prevent sql injection, Activerecord #where, with multiple AND/OR clause

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am fairly new to rails. I have a rails Model 'Message' with: 'belongs_to :sender' and 'belongs_to :receiver' relations.
I am trying to create a message thread between two users: 'current_user' and 'params'.
In the show controller action of the MessagesController, I want to use the equivalent of this sql query:

```
Message.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT *
    FROM messages
    WHERE
        (sender_id = #{current_user.id} OR sender_id = #{params[:id]})
    AND
        (receiver_id = #{current_user.id} OR receiver_id = #{params[:id]});"
)
```

If I where looking for one Message I would use this Activerecord queryto prevent SQL injection:

```
Message.where('sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?', current_user.id, current_user.id).find(params[:id])
```

My current query is:

```
Message.where(sender_id: [current_user.id, params[:id]], receiver_id: [current_user.id, params[:id]])
```

Is this query currently guarded against SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's safe. the final query would be something like `sender_id IN (1, 2) AND receiver_id IN (3, 4)` and all integer values are sanitized. You can simply run tests:

```
Message.where(sender_id: [current_user.id, "' is dangerous"], receiver_id: [current_user.id, params[:id]])
```

and see raw SQL output in console. illegal integers should be converted to 0.